# Can't create SEO friendly URls with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know that there are similar questions but I have tried more solutions from other questions for solving this but without results, this why I asked this question. Thank you very much!

How can I rewrite URLs 
from:

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/mare?lang=ro&cat=bulgaria&tip=mare
```

to

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/ro/bulgaria/mare
```

from

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/hotele-mare?lang=ro&cat=albena
```

to

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/ro/hotele-mare/albena
```

from

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/hotel-mare?lang=ro&id=411
```

to

```
http://www.imperialtranstur.md/ro/hotel-mare/id=411
```

For the first link I tried to write:

```
RewriteRule ^mare/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/ mare.php?lang=$1&cat=$2&tip=$3 [NC,L]
```

and in .php file I wrote:

```
<a href="mare.php?lang='.$_GET['lang'].'&cat='.strtolower($row["Tara"]).'&tip='.$row["tip"].'">'.$row["Tara"].'</a>
```

This is my .htaccess file without rewrite rules for the above URLs:
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    RemoveHandler .html .htm
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang
RewriteRule (.*) $1?lang=ro [R=302,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) with a routing layer does this for you out of the box, no custom code required. Examples include the minimal
[Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) and the full-featured [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) but there are many others worth considering. Rolling your own system will be considerably more painful.

Comment: If you don't want to use a full framework, you should at least look into some routing library. There are several easy to use stand-alone routers you, more or less, can plug into any existing application.